# How to destroy and recreate a Jquery Mobile form element with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile and have a situation which requires me to programmatically create some form fields (select, input, etc) like so:

```
$fieldInput = $('<input type="text" name="' + fieldName + '" />');
```

This works totally fine and Jquery styles the input as expected. The problem comes when the form has to be recreated. I then first "empty" the containing div element using Jquery's .empty() method and then proceed to create the form elements again exactly as above.

The problem is that after the first time, all subsequent attempts to create the form elements result in Jquery Mobile not styling the elements. I am smart enough to work out that this is because I am attempting to create an element which effectively already exists so far as Jquery is concerned and it's getting confused. However, I am not smart enough to know what to do about it... I'm thinking I need to somehow 'unregister' the element before creating it again but I don't know how.

I have tried calling both

```
$fieldInput.trigger('refresh');
```

and

```
$fieldInput.trigger('create');
```

on the elements to no avail. I could go to the lengthy process of rewriting my code so that the elements are only created once at the start and are simply reset when necessary but for reasons I won't go into this would make things a lot more complicated for me.

How can I recreate the same form element (same name, no ID) and still have Jquery Mobile do it's thing? How do I 'unregister' a a Jquery Mobile element?

Comment: If you are "caching" your jquery selectors like so `$fieldInput = $('<input type="text" name="' + fieldName + '" />');` are you setting the variables to null after emptying the containing div? i.e. `$fieldInput  = null;` If not, the reference may be preventing the element from being completely removed and that might mess up jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You know already how to programmatically compose the HTML, so i haven't nothing to learn to You about that, so straight to the point: after you are adding your form elements, you should tell JQM to create the Widgets and update the layout of the container.

Your question is somehow vague about what widgets you need, and below is an example with an `input`, a `textarea` and a `select`. Using `empty()` is just fine.

```js
function createFormElements() {
  var input = [
    '<label for="basic">Text Input:</label>',
    '<input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="">'].join("");
  var textarea = [
    '<label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>',
    '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea">',
    'I\'m a basic textarea.',
    '</textarea>'].join("");
  var select = [
    '<label for="select" class="select">Shipping method:</label>',
    '<select name="select" id="select" data-mini="true">',
    '<option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>',
    '<option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>',
    '<option value="express">Express: next day</option>',
    '<option value="overnight">Overnight</option>',
    '</select>'].join("");
  $("#myForm").empty();
  $(input).appendTo("#myForm");
  $(textarea).appendTo("#myForm");
  $(select).appendTo("#myForm");
  $("#myForm input").textinput();
  $("#myForm textarea").textinput();
  $("#myForm select").selectmenu();
  $(".ui-content").trigger("updatelayout");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="createFormElements();">Create Elements</a>
      <form id="myForm">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```